# Is there any way to make the CSS opacity style apply only to the innerText of the label and not to any of the child elements

Tags: css

I have lots of labels in the following example, where the label contains the input.

**Is there any way to make the CSS opacity style apply to the innerText of the label and not to any of the child elements**, without specifying the color explicitly? In the example below, the opacity has applied to the drop-down, not just the label-proper.

I know I could change the label element to surround only the text and then add a `for=`, but I much prefer to wrap my labels around the labeled thing.

```css
div{ padding: 10px;}

select {
  background-color: white;
}
.colored{
  color: white; 
  background-color: lightblue;
}
   
label {
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
 
<div class="colored">
   <label>
      My white label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>
      My black label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>
<div> 
<label for="select3">Good example</label>
<select id="select3"><option>example that is indeed black-on-white</option></select></div>
```

Comment: [Kosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76917124/13273704) is correct but try searching next time. StackOverflow's comment character limit is too low for me to include them here (and they don't allow URL shorteners), so here's a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/user/CutlerSheridan/comments/15t4ykv/stackoverflow_questions_about_css_opacity/) where I've included links to 11 identical questions, all of which have the same correct answer.

Comment: I have looked at all 11 questions' answers and none of them seem to fit my question.  I want to set the opacity of the label text without changing the background color for the other elements inside the label.  In other words, I'd like my style to work on all labels regardless of their background color.  Opacity is an elegant way to allow a label to be "faded" no matter what the color or background color, but I'm guessing you can't really do so with elements nested inside the label element.

I've edited the example to make it clear I'd like it to work regardless of color.

Comment: Okay I see.  So the question is still the same, but the rgba solution doesn't work for you.  In that case I have an idea but I'll submit it as an answer in a moment instead of describing it in this comment due to its complexity.

Comment: In general, I would recommend using a span tag for text within a label for most cases anyway: `<label><span><input></label>` You'll be able to add styles to just the text using a selector for the span element in your case.

Comment: Actually just do what @ian.pvd said, I was about to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Just seen this and got a bit confused by the 'black on white' as (at least on my IOS/Safari iPad) the select box text is a paleish blue, not black. Perhaps change to say 'the browser's  default setting' - if that is indeed what you want. But if you definitely want black on white you will have to do something to explicity set it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `opacity` applies to the container and everything inside it. But in your case you might use `rgba` `color` instead:

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

select {
  background-color: white;
}

.colored {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.colored label {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}
```

```html
<div class="colored">
  <label>
      My white label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>
      My black label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this style to apply regardless of colors..  I don't want to turn every label white.  I'll modify the example to reflect that.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, you're right, it would be incorrect to make'em all white. So depending on the number of colors used you might specify the corresponding colors for the labels, I believe there are not so many of colors. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest span tags inside of label elements and wrap the text in that. This will allow you to target just the text with opacity (or any other) styles.

I would recommend doing this in general, in case you also need to apply spacing, custom typography, add a pseudo element, replace it with an image, translate the text, etc.

Also – Keep an out for the [color contrast](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html), and make sure the text will be readable for people with low vision.

```css
label {
    /* Demo styles. */
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}

label.light {
    background: white;
}

label.dark {
    background: black;
}

label.cornflowerblue {
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

span {
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: black;
}

label.dark span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <label class="light">
        <span>Dark text on light label</span>
        <select><option>Select Option</option></select>
    </label>
    <label class="dark">
        <span>Light text on dark label.</span>
        <select><option>Select Option</option></select>
    </label>
    <label class="light cornflowerblue">
        <span>Dark text on light blue label.</span>
        <select><option>Select Option</option></select>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the color through a CSS variable in rgb rather than in color-name format then the label can set its own text color opacity without affecting the overall opacity of any children.

i.e. the select will use whatever the default color set in the browser is (which is not always black though).

```css
div{ padding: 10px;}

select {
  background-color: white;
}
div {
--color:0 0 0; /* not really needed = just to stop an undefined value in devtools inspect */
}
.colored {
--color: 255 255 255;
background-color: lightblue;
}
label {
color: rgb(var(--color) / 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="colored">
   <label>
      My white label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>
      My black label
      <select><option>example that should be black-on-white</option></select>
   </label>
</div>
<div> 
<label for="select3">Good example</label>
<select id="select3"><option>example that is indeed black-on-white</option></select></div>
```

Note: for older browsers we'd need to use the comma separated rgba format.